# WCF Post Method, returns 400 Bad Request

Tags: c#, json, wcf, postdata

I see there are many answers to the same question but I am unable to resolve mine, can any one of you please go through my code and resolve my issue please.
I have created a WCF Service as below
The POST Method

Interface (iComplaints.cs)

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare,     ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, UriTemplate = "/insertcomplaint")]
Stream InsertComplaint(ComplaintData data);
```

Class (Complaints.cs)

```
public Stream InsertComplaint(ComplaintData data)
{
    //the code
}
```

DataContract class (ComplaintData)

```
public class ComplaintData
{
   [DataMember]
    public string ComplaintID { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string EntryBy { get; set; }
}
```

I have hosted the service locally and when i try to consume it using the below client method it's giving me 400 (Bad Request)

```
void PostComplaint()
    {
        HttpWebRequest req = null;
        HttpWebResponse res = null;
            string url = "http://localhost:28522/Complaints.svc/insertcomplaint";

            ComplaintData iData = new ComplaintData();
            iData.ComplaintID = txtComplaintID.Text;
            iData.EntryBy = txtEntryBy.Text;

            req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
            req.Method = "POST";
            req.ContentType = "application/json"; 
            req.Headers.Add("SOAPAction", url);

            using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(req.GetRequestStream()))
            {
                streamWriter.Write(iData);
            }

            res = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();
            using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(res.GetResponseStream()))
            {
                var result = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
                TextBox1.Text = result;
            }
    }
```

Web Config of the WCF Service

```
<service behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehavior" name="Complaints">
    <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="webHttp" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="IComplaints" />
   <endpoint contract="IMetadataExchange" binding="mexHttpBinding" address="mex" />
  </service>
```

Please anyone help.

Comment: @Sajeetharan: seriously no... i know i m doing somewhere wrong if you can detect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i guess something is wrong with your serialization.
please check this out:

```
        void PostComplaint()
    {
        HttpWebRequest req = null;
        HttpWebResponse res = null;
        string url = "http://localhost:28522/Complaints.svc/insertcomplaint";

        ComplaintData iData = new ComplaintData();
        iData.ComplaintID = txtComplaintID.Text;
        iData.EntryBy = txtEntryBy.Text;

        req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
        req.Method = "POST";
        req.ContentType = "application/json";
        req.Headers.Add("SOAPAction", url);

        using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(req.GetRequestStream()))
        {
            streamWriter.Write(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(iData));
        }

        res = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();
        using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(res.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            var result = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
            TextBox1.Text = result;
        }

    }
```